# C:\Windows\Logs\DPX\ "setupact.log" 4Gb file - options?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I run a site that is on a Windows  2012 R2 server, and is hosted on a virtual server.

I am paying for 30 Gb of space on the hosting and have been running the site on the same server since 2015.

The site is low on space (about 5Gb left).

About 4 Gb of space is taken up with this file:

C:\Windows\Logs\DPX\setupact.log

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of log file]

The file size is updating every few minutes, and the Date Modified is being updated every few minutes too.

However, the file is so large I can't see what it contains, and I don't know what it's used for.

The file is so large I can't transfer it from the remote desktop to my laptop.

Before I tried to zip the file, or open it, or transfer a copy from the remote desktop to my laptop I turned off the site in IIS and also turned off the MySQL and FileZilla services, to make sure nothing was running on the site side of things but as stated above, I was not able to do anything to investigate what the file contains / why it's growing all the time.

Am I right that I can't delete the file?

Is there any way I can stop it being used / delete it / empty it so it's not so large?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete it because some process is holding it open. Probably something called DPX. Can you rename it? Once it is renamed, whatever is logging to that file will create a new file and the old one will be quiescent; it can then be zipped (likely it will shrink to 5% of its current size or less) and be downloaded.

If you can't rename it, you can set up a rename operation to happen at reboot. In the registry, go to `HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/Session Manager`. Add a new Multi-String value, named `PendingFileRenameOperations`. Double-click to edit it, enter the full path to the file on the first line with a leading `\??\`, as `\??\c:\Windows\Logs\DPX\setupact.log`. On the second line, put the full path to its new name, e.g. `\??\c:\Windows\Logs\DPX\setupact.old`. OK out, close RegEdit, and reboot.

Comment: additional I would suggest that you enable file system compression so that you can if needed save space